# Typeahead.js with comma separated values?

Tags: javascript, typeahead, typeahead.js

So I currently have a form that uses Twitter's typeahead.js. I'm thinking of adding a duplicate form on the same page that uses it too, but I realized a more elegant solution would be to just have one form with values separated by commas, much like google's ngram search (https://books.google.com/ngrams).

I'm wondering if there is a way with the typeahead.js to kinda restart itself when it reaches a comma in the form?

For reference, here is my script that incorporates the typeahead currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
    name: 'people',
    remote: '/name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY',
    minLength: 3
  })
    .keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323650/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-query-by-part-of-typeahead-val

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up and I guess it's not going to be supported:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/134