# Placing the word "and" in text for a list of items

Tags: javascript, html

Hi this is new to all but I have made a program where you can order pizza it displays what i order but i need to make it where the last item has an "and" in the end of it.....example:   You ordered a pizza with hand-tossed crust.
You have the following toppings: pepperoni, hamburger, green peppers, ***AND*** mushrooms.  I need that and in there but can not seem to get it in there. Any help would do here is my little programme

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>PIZZA!</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function vOrder() {
                var strCrust, strOrder, iToppingCount, iMeatCount;

                document.getElementById("taOrder").value = "";

                strCrust = document.getElementById("ddlCrust").value;
                strOrder = "You ordered a pizza with " + strCrust + " crust.\n";

                iToppingCount = 0;
                iMeatCount = 0;
                strToppings = "";


                if (document.getElementById("chkPepperoni").checked) {
                    iToppingCount++;  //same as iToppingCount += 1
                    strToppings += "pepperoni";
                    iMeatCount++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("chkHamburger").checked) {
                    if (iToppingCount > 0)
                        strToppings += ", ";
                    iToppingCount++;
                    strToppings += "hamburger";
                    iMeatCount++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("chkGreenPeppers").checked) {
                    if (iToppingCount > 0)
                        strToppings += ", ";
                    iToppingCount++;
                    strToppings += "green peppers";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("chkMushrooms").checked) {
                    if (iToppingCount > 0)
                        strToppings += ", ";
                    iToppingCount++;
                    strToppings += "mushrooms";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("chkOnion").checked) {
                    if (iToppingCount > 0)
                        strToppings += ", ";
                    iToppingCount++;
                    strToppings += "onions";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("chkSausage").checked) {
                    if (iToppingCount > 0)
                        strToppings += ", ";
                    iToppingCount++;
                    strToppings += "sausage";
                    iMeatCount++;
                }


                if (iToppingCount > 0)
                    strToppings = "You have the following toppings: " + strToppings;
                else
                    strToppings = "Your pizza is a plain cheese.";

                if (iMeatCount > 2)
                    strOrder = "screw you no more then two";
                else

                    strOrder += strToppings;

                document.getElementById("taOrder").value = strOrder;

            }

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            hr {
                color:firebrick;
                height:4px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div style="border-style:groove; border-color:firebrick; border-width:5px; margin:auto; width:4.5in; background-color:bisque">
            <form action="pizza_ddl_chk.html">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">
                            <img src="images/pizza.jpg" width="100" alt="Tasty pizza!" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size:30pt;font-family:Biondi;text-align:center">
                            <span style="color:green">That's</span>  
                            <span style="color:white">A</span>
                            <span style="color:red">Pizza!</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><hr  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Choose your crust:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="ddlCrust">
                                <option value="thin">Thin</option>
                                <option value="thick">Thick</option>
                                <option value="hand-tossed">Hand-tossed</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Choose your toppings:</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Pepperoni</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkPepperoni" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Sausage</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkSausage" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Onion</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkOnion" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hamburger</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkHamburger" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Green Peppers</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkGreenPeppers" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Mushrooms</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkMushrooms" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="button" id="btnOrder" value="Place Your Order" onclick="vOrder()"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><hr  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <textarea id="taOrder" cols="49" rows="4"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not really a defined programming question so much as a question about pizza, isn't it?

Comment: I guess I've never ordered a pizza with "pepperoni, hamburger, green peppers, OR mushrooms."

Comment: This is a fairly common coding problem, and not hard to solve.  You either need to know when you're about to append the last item and add the "AND" before that, or somehow insert the "AND" afterwards (possibly by making the items into an array first, and converting the array into a string at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into 2 parts.

First, prepare your list of ingredients using whatever logic you need:

```
var ingredients = [];
ingredients.push("cheese");
ingreiendts.push("pepperoni");
ingredients.push("tomato");
```

Then create the sentence:

```
var toppings;

if (ingredients.length == 0)
  toppings = "";
else if (ingredients.length == 1)
  toppings = ingredients[0];
else
  toppings = ingredients.slice(0, ingredients.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + ingredients[ingredients.length - 1]
```

This: `ingredients.slice(0, ingredients.length - 1).join(", ")` joins all except the last ingredient together with ', ' as the separator.

`" and " + ingredients[ingredients.length - 1]` just adds the last ingredient onto the string with the text ' and ' inbetween

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically you have to *replace* last comma with an "and". If you already constructed your string, you just need to replace last occurrence of comma in it. There're plenty variation on how to do it, this version uses modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151799/961695):

```
function replaceLastInstance(badtext, str, repl) {
    var charpos = str.lastIndexOf(badtext);
    if (charpos<0) return str;
    ptone = str.substring(0,charpos);
    pttwo = str.substring(charpos+(badtext.length));
    return (ptone+repl+pttwo);
}
```

Using this function, you can simple call:

```
var str = 'You ordered a pizza with hand-tossed crust. You have the following toppings: pepperoni, hamburger, green peppers, mushroom.'

var str2 = replaceLastInstance(',', str, ' and')

console.log(str2);
```

Result is:

> You ordered a pizza with hand-tossed crust. You have the following
>   toppings: pepperoni, hamburger, green peppers and mushroom.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qVbn5/

Comment: "Grammatically you have to replace last comma with an 'and'."  There is considerable disagreement on that point.