# Replace last occurrence word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a problem with replacing last word in JS, I am still searching solution but i cannot get it.

I have this code:

```
var string = $(element).html(); // "abc def abc xyz"
var word   = "abc";
var newWord = "test";

var newV   = string.replace(new RegExp(word,'m'), newWord);
```

I want replace last word "abc" in this string, but now I can only replace all or first occurrence in string. How can I do this? Maybe is not good way?

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2729681/464188

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an idea ....

This is a case-sensitive string search version

```
var str = 'abc def abc xyz';
var word = 'abc';
var newWord = 'test';

// find the index of last time word was used
// please note lastIndexOf() is case sensitive
var n = str.lastIndexOf(word);

// slice the string in 2, one from the start to the lastIndexOf
// and then replace the word in the rest
str = str.slice(0, n) + str.slice(n).replace(word, newWord);
// result abc def test xyz
```

If you want a case-insensitive version, then the code has to be altered. Let me know and I can alter it for you. (PS. I am doing it so I will post it shortly)

**Update:** Here is a case-insensitive string search version

```
var str = 'abc def AbC xyz';
var word = 'abc';
var newWord = 'test';

// find the index of last time word was used
var n = str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(word.toLowerCase());

// slice the string in 2, one from the start to the lastIndexOf
// and then replace the word in the rest
var pat = new RegExp(word, 'i')
str = str.slice(0, n) + str.slice(n).replace(pat, newWord);
// result abc def test xyz
```

**N.B.** Above codes looks for a string. not whole word (ie with word boundaries in RegEx). If the string has to be a whole word, then it has to be reworked.

**Update 2:** Here is a case-insensitive whole word match version with RegEx

```
var str = 'abc def AbC abcde xyz';
var word = 'abc';
var newWord = 'test';

var pat = new RegExp('(\\b' + word + '\\b)(?!.*\\b\\1\\b)', 'i');
str = str.replace(pat, newWord);
// result abc def test abcde xyz
```

Good luck
:)

Answer (score 8):

```
// create array
var words = $(element).html().split(" ");

// find last word and replace it
words[words.lastIndexOf("abc")] = newWord 

// put it back together
words = words.join(" ");
```

Comment: Exactly how I would do it. All these regex answers are too complicated for something simple!

Comment: that just changes the last word, not the last "abc"

Comment: it's fine now but should be `words = words.join(" ")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookahead to get last word in a sentence:

```
var string = "abc def abc xyz";
var repl = string.replace(/\babc\b(?!.*?\babc\b)/, "test");
//=> "abc def test xyz"
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to both:

- match `abc`
- check that there isn't another `abc` afterward in the string

So you can use:

```
abc(?!.*abc)
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, it will fail the whole regex match if what's inside the lookahead is matched.

Also be careful as this would match `abc` in `abcdaire`: if you only want `abc` as a separate word you need to add word boundaries `\b`:

```
\babc\b(?!.*\babc\b)
```

Comment: for some reason `string.replace(/\babc\b(?!.*\babc\b)/, '')` replaces the last abc with a space, do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/11/

Comment: It really shouldn't... This is not just because since you deleted a word, the spaces on the left and right side are now adjacent?

Comment: haha yes it's exactly because of that, i'm stupid. well, good answer then

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript but you can probably twist this to fit your needs:

`(\b\w+\b)(.*)(\1)` replace with `\1\2+'your_key_word'`

[See the demo](http://regex101.com/r/dJ5dG0) to see what I mean.

Comment: Please don't use code spans for something like "JavaScript".

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var string = $(element).html(); // "abc def abc xyz"
var word   = "abc";
var newWord = "test";

var newV   = string.replace(new RegExp(word+'$'), newWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the `replace` method replaces only the first occurrence of the target string if used without the global flag, and try something like:

`"abc def abc xyz abc jkl".split(' ').reverse().join(' ').replace('abc', 'test').split(' ').reverse().join(' ')`