# How do I replace the last occurance of a variable in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I replace the last occurrence of a variable(foo) in a string with "foo"?

I've tried:

```
    var re = new RegExp(".*" + (foo)));
    var newText = currentText.replace(re, someThingElse);
```

Comment: question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136691/replace-last-occurrence-word-in-javascript

Comment: @AliSheikhpour eh.. not really

Answer (score 2):

The negative-lookahead would work, but so will

```
newText = newText.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + foo), "$1somethingElse");
```

Comment: Using a greedy `*` will be better than a negative lookahead if you don't need to use part of the match in the replacement. Also, `.*` will not match over new lines

Comment: Will this also add back the text after foo in my original string?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper in this instance it is the text _before_ that is being replaced back in

Answer (score 1):

Do a negative lookahead to make the match fail if there's another occurrence of the needle

```
function replaceLast(haystack, needle, replacement) {
    // you may want to escape needle for the RegExp
    var re = new RegExp(needle + '(?![\\s\\S]*?' + needle + ')');
    return haystack.replace(re, replacement);
}

replaceLast('foobarfoo', 'foo', 'baz'); // "foobarbaz"
replaceLast('foobarfoo  \n  foobarfoo', 'foo', 'baz'); // "foobarfoo  \n  foobarbaz"
replaceLast('foo    ', 'foo', 'baz'); // "baz    "
```

The advantage of this method is that the replacement is exactly what you expect, i.e. you can use `$1`, `$2`, etc as normal, and similarly if you pass in a *function* the parameters will be what you expect too

```
replaceLast('bar foobar baz', '(b)(a)(r)', '$3$2$1'); // "bar foorab baz"
```