# Right Javascript REGEXP

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this `s55d5bef032706_parameters_0_parameter` and I want to replace the last `_parameter` with `_value`

How would I go about this?

Currently I have the line below which unfortunately replaces all occurrences with value

```
new_id = id.split('_parameter').join('_value');
```

The question asked [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729666/javascript-replace-last-occurence-of-text-in-a-string) is a sentence while mine is a single word therefore solutions are different, I just need to replace the occurrence of '_parameter' in my word

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: replace last occurence of text in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729666/javascript-replace-last-occurence-of-text-in-a-string)

Comment: `new_id = id.replace(/_parameter$/,'_value');`

Comment: Thanks @DalHundal I think I tried this earlier why it didn't work beats. Maybe you need to add it as an answer so that I accept it

Comment: @Juhana I saw that but remember the question there's different in the sense that the string is a sentence while mine is a single word

Comment: Why on earth would that make any difference?

Comment: [The accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2729681) in the duplicate is *exactly the same* as Dal's solution, which you say works.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
new_id = id.replace(/_parameter$/,'_value');
```

Don't forget the $ symbol.